# Change port of Jetbrain Upsource

Tags: linux, port, upsource

First, i googled about the issue, but couldn't find anything.

Issue:
On installation, i changed the `port` to `8081`. But now its used by another app. So, is there any way to change port of `upsource`? (Linux)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the correct way.

1. `./bin/upsource.sh stop`

2.`./bin/upsource.sh configure --base-url=http://(server-name).com:(port) --listen-port=(port)`

3. `./bin/upsource.sh start`

4. Head to http://(server-name).com:(port)

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following from your terminal:

```
./bin/upsource.sh configure --listen-port 1111 --base-url http://servername:1111/
```

Substituting "1111" for the port you want to use and 'servername' with the baseurl you have chosen for upsource (in my case this was the name of my machine).

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/2.5/moving-your-upsource-installation-to-another-server.html

Comment: no, I tried that. it didn't work. Re-installed upsource to fix the issue. Upvoted for help :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is Linux specific, but if you're running Upsource on Windows... the commands in @Wassim Seifeddine's answer can be modified to the following to accomplish port and/or base-url updates for Upsource as shown below:

1. `[upsource-base-path]/bin/upsource.bat stop`
2. `[upsource-base-path]/bin/upsource.bat configure --base-url=http://(server-name).com:(port) --listen-port=(port)`
3. `[upsource-base-path]/bin/upsource.bat start`